# Foreign key is deleted in schema file after every migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have this `AchRelationship` model:

```rb
class AchRelationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
end
```

And an `Account` model:

```rb
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :ach_relationship, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In my `schema.rb` file, I see this line, which makes sense to me:

```
add_foreign_key "ach_relationships", "accounts"
```

However, the issue I'm running into is that whenever I run `rake db:migrate` to add new migrations, that line in my `schema.rb` file gets deleted. It happens even when there are no new migrations. This happens with some members on my team but not all of us. With the other members, whenever they run `rake db:migrate`, they would add that line back if it was gone. So what ends up happening is that we keep seeing that line getting deleted and added back in our PRs and nobody was able to figure out why.

So my question is did I and some other team members do something weird when we set up our database? What can we do to fix this and prevent it from happening again? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migration-overview)

> Active Record will also update your `db/schema.rb` file to match the up-to-date structure of your database.

It means someone on your team has a different database attribute/schema within that table `ach_relationships`. You can ask that person add the `forign_key` manually by migration or via the GUI tool. It actually happens all the time when someone did some migration in some branches and forgot to rollback it after the branch test.

Comment: So to prevent this from happening in the future, we should try to remember to rollback whatever migrations we use to test on another branch? Also, would running `rake db:reset` get rid of this issue and make sure that the database with my `schema.rb` file?

Comment: For the branch test and rollback, right! For the `reset`, it depends. In my case, I update my database constantly, so some of the syntaxes can't apply with the latest version and cause errors with `reset`. In addition, it cost a lot of time running `reset`  as your DB grow up.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll come up with a migration and try to apply see if that will fix the issue for me. Thank you!